# MacBook Air shutting down randomly

Tags: hardware

My MacBook Air 2020 keeps shutting down randomly with shutdown cause 8/3 and -11 with the sometimes wrong date on the log (1970).

Thought that could be due to the high temperature on the processor so I put a thermal pad on the CPU and GPU and installed the Turbo Boost app with no success.

Answer (score 2):

Shutdown codes `3` and `-11` indicate that the power button was held down for an extended period of time and caused a forced shutdown. If you aren't manually holding down the button, one possibility is that there is a short circuit across it. Did the system perhaps experience a liquid spill or mechanical damage recently?